# Mysql split a column into to two values(numbers) and search between those

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, split

Hi I have this issue in mysql, My Table is something like below

```
  id        years

  1       1985-1996
  2       1990-2000
```

now I will receive a submitted value(yeaer between two,ex 1990)  I have to split years into two parts like 1985 as initVal and 1996 endVal

I tried a few things which did not work for me

```
SELECT * FROM cip_finder WHERE model =33 AND('1986' BETWEEN if(locate('_',years)=0,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(years, '_', 1)) AND if(locate('_',years)=0,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(years, '_', 1)))


SELECT *,SPLIT_STR(years, '-', 1) AS initVAL,SPLIT_STR(years, '-', 2) AS endVal FROM cpc_finder WHERE model =33 AND('1986' BETWEEN initVal AND endVal)
```

is there any solution for this

Comment: Normalize your data. Your intention is to search through two columns, so make your `years` to be as `yearFrom` and `yearTill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Alma Do's comment... you need to normalize your the years column into two.

Although if you're still in a situation if you can't do that, use the query below and you will get the expected output:

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX( years , '-', 1) AS initVal, 
REPLACE(years,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX( years , '-', 1),'-'),'') AS endVal 
FROM cip_finder;
```

Hope that helps!